# Connecting to WS:// websocket (unsecure) in https site

Tags: javascript, html, websocket, mqtt

I am trying to connect to a unsecure websocket from https site.

I got an error:

> VM40:164 Mixed Content: The page at
>   'https://username.github.io/reponame/' was loaded over HTTPS, but
>   attempted to connect to the insecure WebSocket endpoint
>   'ws://192.168.2.152:9001/mqtt'. This request has been blocked; this
>   endpoint must be available over WSS.

Is there any way I can connect to unsecured WebSocket from https site?

If not, I want to test my website.
I can open **http://localhost:port** on PC, but I need to test from android browser too. But, I cannot access it from my android device in the same network using the **http://IP:port**.

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: There are 2 totally separate question here, split this in to 2 questions. Also you need to tell us what browser you are using in order to solve the first one. For the second question, when you repost it, include details of how you are serving your page and the platform you are serving it from.

Comment: A WebSocket on a secure page (https://) is not allowed to connect to an unsecure server (ws://), only to a secure server (wss://). The opposite is allowed, though. A WebSocket on an unsecure page can connect to either an unsecure or secure server.